# What is the sense of non-IDR I-frames with recovery points SEI and exact_match=1 in a h264 stream

Tags: h.264

I understand the difference between an IDR frame (=this and every frame after this frame can be decoded without reference to previous frames) and an I-frame (this frame can be decoded without reference to any other frame (including any previous frame).

As far as I understand, "previous" in the definition above refers to decode order (the order of the NAL units in the byte stream / file), not presentation order (the order the frames are shown on screen).

This would mean that in theory a P or B frame *after* an I-frame can depend on a frame *before* the I-frame (even though I understand that "well behaved" h264 streams don't do this, it is allowed in the spec).

However it is possible to add a "recovery point SEI message" to some (or all) I-frames, which basically says "you can start decoding here if you want and you will see something decent. Makes sense to me -- a user might be ok with the first couple of frames after they start watching to have some artefacts (better than not being able to show anything until the next IDR-frame); however if you really want the best quality you should start decoding at the previous IDR.

However, according to the [spec](https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-H.264) (08/21; annex D.2.8), this recovery point SEI may have a flag `exact_match=1`, which means "if you start decoding here, you get exactly the same frames, as if you started decoding at the previous IDR.

Now, my question, why does this exist? Why (as an encoder) go through all the trouble of putting all this info in a SEI message, when (afaict) this frame is exactly the same as an IDR frame.....

---

Update: after a couple of hours of digging, I have a theory but I would be very happy if an expert could confirm.

With a non-IDR I-frame the following might be possible (frames listed in decoding/bitstream order; decoding pos is the how many'th frame this is in the bitstream, presentation pos the how many'th frame it is to display to the user (table starts somewhere halfway the stream, there were frames before this one)

| type | decoding pos | presentation pos |
| --- | --- | --- |
| I | 6 | 8 |
| B | 7 | 6 |
| B | 8 | 7 |
| P | 9 | 12 |
| B | 10 | 9 |
| B | 11 | 10 |

In words, although we could start decoding at the I-frame, and every frame *in presentation order* afterwards would be an `exact_match`, however there are still frames *in decoding order* afterwards that refer to earlier frames (i.e. the first 2 B-frames will not be decodable without a previous frames).

Comment: Google Open GOP.

Comment: OK, I did. So my conclusion is that indeed my "Update" section was correct; but with the additional remark that making every I frame an IDR frame (closed GOP) results in worse compression (since you can't use B frames before your IDR in presentation order)

Answer (score 1):

It took a while, but I now have an answer that I'm 99% certain of -- at least for my stream (JVC camcorder -- MPEGTS file)....

So the stream (in presentation order) looks like (I is an IDR frame, `i` is an I-frame without IDR (but with recovery point as described in the question):

```
BBIBBPBBPBBPBBiBBPBBPBBPBBiBBPBBPBBPBBiBBPBBPBBPBBiBBPBBPBBPBBi....BBPBBPBBPBBIBB...
```

The space between I frames is 12 frames, the space between IDR frames is every 25th I-frame (so every 300 frames).

If I add the decode order to the first 12 frames, we see this (this is regardless of whether the I frame is IDR or not):

```
BBIBBPBBPBBP
120453786ab9
```

So in decode order this looks like (with presentation order underneath):

```
IBBPBBPBBPBB
201534867b9a
```

In words: each non-B frame is decoded 2 frames "earlier" than it is in presentation stream.

Normally B frames will refer both to a previous and a following frame (in presentation order; in decode order both frames will have to be earlier). Normally a B frame (in presentation order) right before an I frame will refer to this I frame and the preceding P frame (and this is what happens in most of the stream).

However the two B frames in presentation order right before the IDR frame, come in decode order after the IDR frame. The IDR frame means that the decoder can forget any previous frames, so these B frames *cannot* refer to the preceding P frame. So they only refer to the IDR frame (which follows it in presentation time).

This means that the B frames right before an IDR frame are slightly less compressed (since they only have one reference frame) than those before a non-IDR I-frame. So using more non-IDR I-frames (with recovery message) leads to a (marginally) better bitrate (or better quality for the same bitrate).

Note that the Non-IDR I-frames with recovery message only specify that all frames in *presentation* order after this I-frame can be decoded. The two B frames that follow this I-frame in decode order can not be decoded when starting at the given I-frame.

Also note that the example stream given below actually starts (in presentation order) with two B frames and then an IDR frame; these are real frames than can be decoded since they only refer to the IDR frame (even though many video players will skip them, if you ask `ffmpeg` to extract the first frame, it will deliver that one).

Interestingly, if you take this file and have `ffmpeg` remux it to mp4, the first two B frames receive a `AV_PKT_FLAG_DISCARD` flag, and the IDR frame is now the first frame according to `ffmpeg`.

More interesting information: This particular JVC camcorder splits the video file when there is a risk of exceeding 4GB, and it does so on a random I-frame (in presentation time). This means there is a 96% chance than the subsequent file starts with the sequence:

```
BBiBBPBBPBBPBB....
```

which means that in this case those two first B frames cannot be decoded.